# window.open won't work on button created with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I have the following html loaded into a div on my webpage:

```
<style>
    #site h1{
        margin: 1em 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 2em;
    }
    #site h2 {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #site p {
        margin: 0 0 1em 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #site button {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0.5em auto;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #913D88;
        border: none;
        padding: 0.5em;
    }
</style>

<div id="site">
</div>
<br />
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
       var url = "JSON/sites.json";       
       $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
           var siteHTML ="";
           $.each(response, function(index, site) {
                siteHTML += "<h1>" + site.name + "</h1>";               
                siteHTML += "<p>" + site.reviewText + "</p>";
                siteHTML += "<button type='button' value='" + site.url + "'>Go check it out</button>";
                siteHTML += "<hr>";
           }); //ends callback loop
           $('#site').html(siteHTML);
       }); //end get JSON
       $('button').click(function (event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           var url = $(this).attr('value');
           window.open(url);
           });
    });  //end document ready
</script>
```

Basically, what this does is it loads data from a JSON file, then creates some html tags, and a button which should contain the url as a value. Here's the JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Traffic Monsoon",
    "url":"https://trafficmonsoon.com/land.php?id=1&ref=Shooshly",
    "reviewText" : "A good feeder site. I'm seeing 15 to 20 ads daily, bringing me to 10 to 15 cents a day. Takes me about 5 minutes, wich for the pay is a good day. The best thing is, if you gain a referral, he brings you 100% of his clicks, or another 10 to 15 cents. You have to surf 10 pages though, which takes you about 4 minutes. But with 10 referrals, that's a buck a day. They also offer credits for surfing, which opens up your page to other people. They also offer revenue sharing positions, 55 bucks for 50, that I can't yet comment on. No info to be found on the expected ROI. "
  },
  {
    "name":"Neobux",
    "url":"http://www.neobux.com/m/v/?rh=53686F6F73686C79",
    "reviewText" : "Respect you elders! A site paying for 7 years will greet you with ads worth about 3 cents a day. A minimum payout of 3$ means you'll be clicking your way for three months or so. It gives you offers to work and earn on crowdflower, but Clixsence is might be better for that. My personal experience says that the rented referrals require a costly upgrade of 90$ per year for them to be profitable, unless you're content with making a few cents a year ... No really, as a free member, you have to work hard to find the hidden gems. So, rather cashout and reinvest. Though the free click bonus seems to drop after you cashout ... "
  },
  {
    "name":"Inadbux",
    "url":"http://www.inadbux.com/?ref=Mojtomas",
    "reviewText":"One of the sites that proves it can take care of itself. Active rented referrals that together brought in 3.60$ in the first month. On top of that you gain 10 to 15 cents from you own clicks. The site's still a new one, so proceed with caution. "
  },
    {
    "name":"Inadclicks",
    "url":"http://www.inadclix.com/?ref=Shooshly",
    "reviewText":"Sister site to inadbux. Again, One of the sites that proves it can take care of itself. Active rented referrals that together brought in 3.60$ in the first month. On top of that you gain 10 to 15 cents from you own clicks, while you can buy direct referrals with a 6 level downline for 2.50 per one. The site's still a new one, so proceed with caution. "
  },
    {
    "name":"Clixsence",
    "url":"http://www.clixsense.com/?7339208",
    "reviewText":" A site paying for years. You can easily do 3 to 5$ a day on this site, working through surveys and doing crowdflower tasks. You gain a bonus for completing certain daily tasks so yeah. On the PTC side, expect to get 0.03 to 0.04$ daily. There are no rental referrals, but a good ref downline that can earn you a ton of cash. A high payout of 8$ still makes it a good feeder for other sites. "
  },
    {
    "name":"Ultimateclixx",
    "url":"http://www.ultimateclixx.com/?ref=Shooshly",
    "reviewText":"A good site. You gain up to 10 cents a day, but it is my first choice deposit wise. Offering rented referrals, buying direct referrals on the market for as low as 0.75$, this makes it one of the best. Boasting the cheapest investement upgrades (10 to 15$ a month), this makes it a prime for building your income. All statistics open for view, wonderful and helpful admin, great and guick support, this is pretty much a must. I see this one running for a long way to come. "
  }
]
```

Now when I click on the button nothing happens. I tried doing `console.log($('button').attr('value'));` with the page opened in browser, and I get back `undefined` and in the next line 1 url (the first one from the JSON file).

I'm gussing the problem is that the value of the button contains 2 values, an undefined object and an url? What did I do wrong, I can't figure it out. Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you try to move the button click event into the getJSON function (after the .html(..) line?

Comment: The getJSON operation happend async so it's occur after the button click binding happends

Comment: moved it and it worked. Write it up as an anwser, and I'll accept it. Thanks

Comment: you need to bind your button under $.each loop

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič I wrote it as an answer, please accept, 10x :-)

Comment: much better if use document.createElement() rather then the string format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the button click event into the getJSON function (after the .html(..) line

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
       var url = "JSON/sites.json";       
       $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
           var siteHTML ="";
           $.each(response, function(index, site) {
                siteHTML += "<h1>" + site.name + "</h1>";               
                siteHTML += "<p>" + site.reviewText + "</p>";
                siteHTML += "<button type='button' value='" + site.url + "'>Go check it out</button>";
                siteHTML += "<hr>";
           }); //ends callback loop
           $('#site').html(siteHTML);
           $('button').click(function (event) {
               event.preventDefault();
               var url = $(this).attr('value');
               window.open(url);
           });
       }); //end get JSON
    });  //end document ready
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating button dynamically. In that case you should use .on() jquery method to attach event. Here is the code.

```js
$(document).on('click','button',function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var url = $(this).attr('value');
      window.open(url);
});
```